# Class trajopt_interface/TrajOptPlanner cannot be found in Moveit tutorials

Tags: moveit, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ROS community. After successfully testing TrajOpt using the tutorial from [ROS Industrial Training](https://industrial-training-master.readthedocs.io/en/melodic/_source/demo3/index.html), I decided to try the fairly new tutorial provided in [Moveit! master branch](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/trajopt_planner/trajopt_planner_tutorial.html). Following the steps mentioned in the latter tutorial, I created a new workspace with both moveit and panda_moveit_config from source. No major compilation errors were found, so I just source it and run the first roslaunch.

```
roslaunch panda_moveit_config demo.launch  pipeline:=trajopt
```

However, it was followed by the error

```
[ERROR] [1572464829.624886189]: Exception while loading planner 'trajopt_interface/TrajOptPlanner': According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class trajopt_interface/TrajOptPlanner with base class type planning_interface::PlannerManager does not exist. Declared types are  chomp_interface/CHOMPPlanner lerp_interface/LERPPlanner ompl_interface/OMPLPlanner
Available plugins: chomp_interface/CHOMPPlanner, lerp_interface/LERPPlanner, ompl_interface/OMPLPlanner
```

My first reaction was a problem with the source. Even removed the ros-melodic-panda-moveit-config, source it again, but the same problem still persisted. Then when to confirm which branches were being used: master for moveit and melodic-level for the panda configuration. Seems fine. As such, I cannot figure out why this particular class cannot be found. Thanks for the help in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/336477/class-trajopt_interface/trajoptplanner-cannot-be-found-in-moveit-tutorials/) by [andreflorindo](https://answers.ros.org/users/47703/andreflorindo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-10-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems that there is a [CATKIN_IGNORE](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/tree/06a9e4beac1e94d862c8286a22561529cb03d638/moveit_planners/trajopt) file in the `trajopt_planner` package in the master branch of MoveIt. This means the package will not get build and hence will not be found when launching the demo.

I guess this follows from the sentence:

> The TrajOpt planner is still an alpha feature [...]

But maybe we can add an [issue](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_tutorials/issues) that this is not clear from the tutorial?

---

Originally posted by [jeroendm](https://answers.ros.org/users/36697/jeroendm/) with karma: 168 on 2020-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [andreflorindo](https://answers.ros.org/users/47703/andreflorindo/) on 2020-01-17**:
Couple weeks later figured out the same by reviewing the commit [#1593](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/pull/1593). At the time I tried to remove the CATKIN_IGNORE in a hope that would solve the problem, but some errors in the compilations still persisted. Anyway, ended up using Trajopt with Tesseract.

**Comment by [andreflorindo](https://answers.ros.org/users/47703/andreflorindo/) on 2020-01-17**:
Although is mentioned that Trajopt in moveit is a "alpha feature...and needs further hardening", there is also no reference of a CATKIN_IGNORE in the moveit master branch tutorial for [Trajopt](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/trajopt_planner/trajopt_planner_tutorial.html).